# JavaScript - Mouse position relative to rotated element. - Vertical paper-slider

Tags: javascript, css, polymer-2.x

I am trying to create an user interface with multiple sliders. These sliders should have different angles and should also be useable with multiple fingers at the same time.

When I use polymers `<paper-slider>` element it works even with multiple user inputs. But as soon as i use `style="transform: rotate(-90deg);"` it is not really useable anymore. I have to drag horizontally although i want to move it vertically.

So I decided to create a custom element. Is there any possibility to get the x and y position of the mouse relative to a div (especially when rotated)?

I know about `this.getBoundingClientRect()` from the mouse position, but this only works when my element is not nested inside of other polymer elements and the element is not rotated.

Are there any ideas to solve this problem?
It would be great if i can fix this inside of my control no matter what rotation-style is applied outside.

**Example:**

```css
paper-slider{
  margin-top: 100px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw-dot-custom-elements.appspot.com/PolymerElements/paper-slider/v2.0.2/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://raw-dot-custom-elements.appspot.com/PolymerElements/paper-slider/v2.0.2/paper-slider/paper-slider.html">

<paper-slider></paper-slider>
```

Comment: There is `s-slider` which is built using `paper-slider` with few other features that also include vertical slider. For more info:https://www.webcomponents.org/element/StartPolymer/s-slider/demo/demo/index.html